# Member Status Rules. Should be simple, but not for this newbie. CiviCRM 5.40.2 on D9

Tags: civimember, status, rules

How would I set up Status Rules for what I assume are the simple membership conditions shown below? It seemed straightforward, but I've gotten myself totally confused. Using CiviCRM 5.40.2 on Drupal 9.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- **New** starts on "start date" and member is "new" for 6 months
- **Current** starts on "start date" and continues until "end date." So both New and Current members are current
- **Grace** starts on "end date" and continues for 3 more months as a grace period; then the member's membership really ends
- **Expired** starts on the end date adjusted by the grace period, and remains expired thereafter

Answer (score 3):

It may help you to compare with https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/member/membershipStatus?reset=1 or one of the other demo sites.

This is the default settings and it could be you just need to set your New back to running off Member Since, not Start Date. And then also tweak the other dates as required.

[image]

Comment: Its worth pointing out that CiviCRM tries each rule in turn until it finds one that matches. Also worth reading the documentation (which uses join date for member since) at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/#membership-status-rules

Comment: Well, gee. Ok. I think I'm starting to get it. Apologies this thank you is so late in coming. I do appreciate it.

Comment: @petednz Thank you for the visual.